# Detecting the visitor's browser by JAVASCRIPT or PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, browser, user-agent

I am curious to know if detecting the visitor browser with client-side script is more reliable than server-side script?

It is easy and popular to get the visitor browser both by `PHP` and `Javascript`. In the former one, we analyze `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` sent by the header array. However, header is not always reliable. Can `Javascript` be more reliable as it get the visitor browser from the visitor's machine?

I mean is it possible to miss the USER AGENT in header and get the browser by javascript?

**UPDATE:** Please do not introduce methods such as `jQuery` as I am familiar with them. I just want to know if it's possible for header's user agent to fail when javascript still can detect browser? Comparison of client-side and server-side methods.

Comment: what do you mean by "not always reliable"?

Comment: This is the essence of my question. For example, you cannot rely on header to pass the referrer. May header fail to deliver USER_AGENT?

Comment: Test it! Do both PHP and JavaScript methods, and try it on a number of sufferer

Comment: Browsers* stupid mobile version wont let me fix thay

Comment: @JonathonReinhart This is what one cannot test. It can should be tested on different browsers (tens of active ones), OSes (several major ones), etc. This is the reason that I asked this question.

Comment: Why can one not test this? If one cares so much about the data one wants to get, one can put forth the effort to *verify* it is working, and not simply believe a bunch of strangers' opinions.

Comment: How can I install several Operating System, and tens of available browsers to test this? How many computers I must have and how many days I must install softwares to perform this test? Even in this case, internet connection and ISP can also be effective, and I must travel around the world to test this.

Comment: see my answer to your original question --- i see that you have many more :)

Comment: "Please do not introduce methods such as jQuery" — Why have you tagged this question *jQuery* then?

Comment: @Quentin Because I want to compare jQuery method (client-side) and PHP method (server-side). I know the methods, I want to know their differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. So User-Agent header is not required by RFC

> User agents SHOULD include this field with requests.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.43

Which means the server side detection is not guaranteed.

Similarly client side detection typically relies on `navigator.userAgent` but that is also provided by the user agent (browser or what not) and similarly cannot be guaranteed.

Thus the answer to your question is 50/50 :)

Now, if you are trying to figure out how to handle different browsers - feature detection is your safest bet here - but that's a different question ;)

Comment: very nice clarification of the issue. Thus, you mean there is not much difference between server-side and client-side analysis?

Comment: yes, with a caveat that you can potentially learn more about the user agent from the javascript by testing for certain features - this is called feature detection.

Answer (score 2):

The User-Agent can be tested server side or client side, either way it can be spoofed.

You can finger print the browser with JavaScript (seeing what methods and objects the browser provides) and use that to infer the browser, but that is less precise and JavaScript can be disabled / blocked / edited by the client.

So neither is entirely reliable.

It is generally a bad idea to do anything based on the identify of the browser though.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use the server side detection.

If a user wants to mask their browser, their browser will likely be masked on both ends.

If you want to find out their browser for HTML compatibility, they should be expecting mildly broken pages if they've masked their browser (but you should always try your best not to have browser specific HTML). If it's for javascript compatibility, they should also be expecting some broken javascript.

Comment: Thanks for an explicit answer!

Comment: As a corollary, if they have a crappy browser that, for some reason, doesn't pass a reasonable user agent header, they should be quite used to a broken pages already!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [$.browser()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/) in jquery

Answer (score 0):

A different angle: why do we want to detect the browser?

In the case of analytics, there isn't much you can do really. Anyone that does a little research can send whatever user agent string they like, but who's going to go through all the trouble ;)

If we're talking about features to enable/disable on a website, you should really be going for *feature detection*. By focusing on what the browser can/can't do, instead of what it calls itself, you can generally expect that browser to perform whatever action reliably if the feature you need is present.

More info: http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/detect-browser/

Answer (score 0):

One big advantage to use client-side javascript is that you can get much more information about the browser.

Here is an interesting example: https://panopticlick.eff.org/